# Using python and ArcGIS to create custom maps in Power BI

Tags: python, powerbi

I have been using the arcGIS API for python to create maps that work well in Juypter notebooks. my question is if its possible to run the same python visual in a Power BI's  report via the python visualization. My initial attempts have not worked and I'm not clear how to render visualizations from python code. for the following demo, outlined in the link, what script would i need to run within the python visualiation in order to see the map in power bi?

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
my_gis = GIS()
m = my_gis.map()
m
```

The reason why i am looking at this is to build more custom visualizations that are currently not possible with the out of box Arc GIS visualation available in power bi.

Here is a link to the installation and a basic demo of the ArcGIS in python' sJupyter notebook. Its using anaconda python.

[ArcGIS API For Python | ArcGIS Developer](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/install-and-set-up/)